# How to wrap content in sections divided by h4 elements at varying depths with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

What can I do to surround the content between each `h4` element within the `main` element with `section` tags, when the depth of the `h4` elements varies? In the example below, lines 3 to 5, lines 7 to 11, and lines 12 to 14 should each be wrapped with `section` tags.

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="styling-div"><h3>Main Heading 1</h3></div>
  <h4>Subheading</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
  <img src="src">
  <div class="styling-div"><div class="another-div"><h3>Main Heading 2</h3></div></div>
  <h4>Subheading</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
  <div class="styling-div-for-h5"><h5>Sub-subheading</h5></div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <div class="styling-div-for-h4"><h4>Subheading</h4></div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <figure>Image</figure>
</main>
```

What would be a suitable algorithm to find and place the section tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html_text = '''\
<main class="main">
  <div class="styling-div"><h3>Main Heading 1</h3></div>
  <h4>Subheading</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
  <img src="src">
  <div class="styling-div"><div class="another-div"><h3>Main Heading 2</h3></div></div>
  <h4>Subheading</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
  <div class="styling-div-for-h5"><h5>Sub-subheading</h5></div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <div class="styling-div-for-h4"><h4>Subheading</h4></div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <figure>Image</figure>
</main>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

def is_h4_or_contains_h4(tag):
    return tag.name == 'h4' or tag.find('h4')

def is_h1234_or_contains_h1234(tag):
    tags = {'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4'}
    return tag.name in tags or tag.find(tags)

for tag_in_main in soup.select('.main > *'):
    if is_h4_or_contains_h4(tag_in_main):

        s = '\n<section>\n'
        for sibling in tag_in_main.find_next_siblings():
            if is_h1234_or_contains_h1234(sibling):
                break
            s += str(sibling) + '\n'
            sibling.extract()
        s += '</section>\n'
        tag_in_main.insert_after(BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser'))

# clear empty lines
soup.smooth()
main = soup.select_one('.main')
for i, c in enumerate(main.contents):
    if isinstance(c, NavigableString):
        main.contents[i].replace_with('\n')

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<main class="main">
<div class="styling-div"><h3>Main Heading 1</h3></div>
<h4>Subheading</h4>
<section>
<p>Text</p>
<img src="src"/>
</section>
<div class="styling-div"><div class="another-div"><h3>Main Heading 2</h3></div></div>
<h4>Subheading</h4>
<section>
<p>Text</p>
<div class="styling-div-for-h5"><h5>Sub-subheading</h5></div>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
</section>
<div class="styling-div-for-h4"><h4>Subheading</h4></div>
<section>
<p>Text</p>
<figure>Image</figure>
</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I couldn’t come up with the idea that adding str repeatedly.

Comment: @AndrejKesley This is just sheer curiosity but why do you use string operations instead of native BeautifulSoup methods

Comment: @Blye One could always create new `<section>` tag and reparent the correct `<h4>`s sibling tags, but for me creating new html string it's easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do to wrap parts of main in sections that are started by h4 tags at varying depths is iterate through the children of the main tag.

By checking if each child either is or contains an h4 tag you know you need to insert a section element before it and insert the child into it. If the child does not meet the condition you just insert it into the section last created or just leave it be if no section has been created yet.

Comment: Thanks for your idea and revise. @Andrej ‘s code worked. Cause I’m not a persistent English speaker, I’m always grateful for such revise.